# Javascript - How to null the Underlying Reference?

Tags: javascript, reference

given this javascript code:

```
this.underlyingReference = {name: 'joe'};

this.nullMe(this.underlyingReference);

alert(this.underlyingReference.name);

function nullMe(variable) {
   variable = null;
}
```

Is there a way in Javascript for me to null this.underlyingReference using "variable"? I want to be able to null out variable and have the underlying reference be nulled and not simply null the reference to a reference.

I've read articles like this one http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass about Javascript's pass by reference functionality but it appears as though when you want to destroy the underlying reference the behavior is not what I have come to expect from references.

when execution passes the second line of code I want "this.underlyingReference" to be nulled out. However the alert line shows that the underlying reference is still alive and kicking.

Comment: JavaScript always passes by value. The confusion is that sometimes that value is a reference.

Comment: @MattGreer: any object (that is quite alot) is passed by reference.

Comment: A reference to the object is passed by value.

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny :) there is a difference between passing references by value and actually passing by reference, as this question here illustrates. I'm on an iPad right now so have limited ability to explain. In the OP's function, it receives a new copy of the original reference, and that copy gets nulled out, causing the confusion. See SimoneGianni's answer.

Comment: @MattGreer: actually you're right. I just thought about it and looked into the spec. Pretty confusing, but calling it 'passing a reference by value' really hits the matter exactly. You can't change the original object itself (since it was passed by value and therefore is a local copy) but you can modify the original objects properties through the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
function nullMe(obj, reference){
    delete obj[reference];
}

nullMe(this, "underlyingReference");
```

Or

```
function nullMe(reference){
    delete this[reference];
}
nullMe.call(this, "underlyingReference");
```

Answer (score 4):

why not just assign null to that property:

```
this.underlyingReference = null;
alert(this.underlyingReference);// null
```

or, if you want to destroy the property, you can use delete:

```
delete this.underlyingReference;
alert(this.underlyingReference);// undefined
```

if you still want to have a function call, you can use this setup:

```
var NullMe = function(obj, propName) 
{
    obj[propName] = null;
    //OR, to destroy the prop:
    delete obj[propName];
}
NullMe(this, 'underlyingReference');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a confusion between the "old by reference", used in Pascal and in C in some cases, and the "by reference" in java, javascript and most recent programming languages.

In javascript, a value is passed, and that value is a reference to the object. That mean you can change the object following that reference, but not change the reference itself.

If you need to do that in a method, then you need to do it "explicitly", for example :

```
this.nullMe("underlyingReference");
this.nullMe = function(name) {
    this[name] = null;
}
```

But it's a bit, well, over-engineering to have a method to set null :)

Comment: I don't have a nullMe method in my actual code, this was just the smallest reproducible version of the problem.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. The suggestion to use `this[name]`, on the other hand ...